# How to combine multiple strings into one Python list?

Tags: python

How do I combine multiple strings into one Python list? I haven't been able to find any Stack Overflow posts addressing this issue.

I created an earlier program that outputted many strings like this:

```
print(outputted_strings) = 

Susan has a cat
Susan has a dog
Susan has a lizard
Susan has a hamster
... (and so on)...
```

How can I combine this all into one list? like this:

```
list = ['Susan has a cat', 'Susan has a dog', 'Susan has a lizard', 'Susan has a hamster', ...]
```

Comment: try using .append()

Comment: That output is one string with newlines in it. Use `outputted_strings.splitlines()`

Comment: Using... what? "Add a comma to the end of every line" is a basic functionality of most editors (although you might have to resort to regex). And [] you can add yourself.

Comment: The reason you are having difficulty putting the strings into a list is that, using this code, you don't **have** the strings - you merely *display* them.

Answer (score 2):

Using [splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) OR [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

More info about it [using splitlines()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/splitlines), [using split](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split)

```
outputted_strings = """Susan has a cat
Susan has a dog
Susan has a lizard
Susan has a hamster"""

more_strings = "hello\nthere\nhope\nyou're\ngood"

print(outputted_strings)
print(outputted_strings.splitlines())

print(more_strings)
print(more_strings.split('\n'))
```

Output:

```
Susan has a cat
Susan has a dog
Susan has a lizard
Susan has a hamster
['Susan has a cat', 'Susan has a dog', 'Susan has a lizard', 'Susan has a hamster']
hello
there
hope
you're
good
['hello', 'there', 'hope', "you're", 'good']
```

`split()` is more flexible in the way that it lets you choose the criteria to split the strings on (in this case we used `\n` new line separator, but it can be anything).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, if you have that chunk of text as a string, you can use `splitlines` to get the list you want.

```
>>> test = """foo
... bar
... baz
... """
>>> test.splitlines()
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>>
```